# App gets slow when parsing image using json in ios 5

Tags: ios, json

I'm new to ios development.My app gets slower when i'm parsing image using json parser in ios 5.
Please could anybody help to solve this problem.

```
-(NSDictionary *)Getdata
{
    NSString  *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url link"];
    urlString = [urlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json;
    if (data) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSLog(@"json...%@",json);
    }

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        // Handle Error and return
        //    return;
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem isn't exactly helpful. It's unclear to me if everything in your app is slow, or just certain operations; if you exprience a slow action and then it becomes fast again or if it continues to perform slowly.

Whatever, the general rule is to performan all network communication including the parsing of the answer on a separate thread, i.e. not on the main thread that is responsible for managing the user interface. That way the app remains responsive and appears to be fast.

If you can download the images separately, you can already display the result and put a placeholder where the image will appear. Later, when you have received the image you remove the placeholder and put the image there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.I want to parse 3 image,only that view controller is slow.The App is fine with other viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably the culprit.

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

If you're calling this on the main thread (and because you haven't mentioned threads at all I suspect that you are) it will block everything and wait until the server has responded.

This is a spectacularly bad experience for the user :)

You need to do all of this on a background thread and notify the main thread when you're done. There's a couple of ways of doing this (NSOperation etc) but the simplest is just this :

```
// Instead of calling 'GetData', do this instead
[self performSelectorOnBackgroundThread:@selector(GetData) withObject:nil];


// You can't return anything from this because it's going to be run in the background
-(void)GetData {
    ...
    ...

    // Instead of 'return json', you need to pass it back to the main thread
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(GotData:) withObject:json waitUntilDone:NO];
}


// This gets run on the main thread with the JSON that's been got and parsed in the background
- (void)GotData:(NSDictionary *)json {
    // I don't know what you were doing with your JSON but you should do it here :)
}
```